# NIC spontaneously switches between 100 and 1000 Mbit

Tags: linux-networking

My dual NIC MSI motherboard recently started **jumping between 100 and 1,000 Mbit**, causing up to several seconds of connection loss, which is critical during these work-at-home times with video conferencing. The issue is present when the system is running Fedora Linux but, but goes away when booting Windows 10. Multiple cables, switches and even other NICs were tried to no avail.

This **seems** to be load dependent.

Log output when trying the r8169 adapter. Same results, but worded slightly different when using the onboard NICs.

```
[  192.520815] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[  229.044928] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[  232.641128] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  309.081390] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[  312.684481] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[  449.145256] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[  452.927153] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  539.187973] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
```

- OS: Fedora 32
- Platform: X86_64
- Motherboard: MSI Mag Z390 Tomahawk
- Onboard NICs tried: Intel I219-V (igb driver), Intel I211 (e2000e driver)
- Alternate NICs tried: Intel CT Desktop Adapter (e2002 driver), LogiLink PC0029A (r8169 driver)
- Switches tried: EdgeSwitch 24, HP ProCurve
- Cables tried: A wide variety of CAT5 to CAT6 cables

Goal: Having a Linux system which doesn't spontaneously switch between 100 Mbit and 1,000 Mbit, so applications like Teams and Slack doesn't throw fits over lost connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having given numerous excuses to my coworkers, tested a pile of hardware (including a stack of recently purchased, but somewhat cheap Realtek NICs), looked through MBs of log files and read up on kernel parameters, I've found the culprit.

Deciding that this probably was software related, I booted my system in single user mode and ran the command line version of **speedtest** from Ookla. It reflected the bandwith advertised by my ISP - around 500/500Mbit. At no point did it fall back to 100 Mbit.

Booting in multi user mode again, and the problem was back. When left alone for a couple of minutes, the NIC would fall back to 100 Mbit. When running speedtest again, the NIC would renegotiate the link to 1,000 Mbit about 2-5 seconds into the test. About a minute of so after the test completed, the NIC was back to 100 Mbit.

Armed with *systemctl stop*, I started going through the daemons running on the system one by one. Finally I found the gremlin hiding in my system: **tuned**

When I stopped **tuned**, the issue was resolved. Upon closer inspection, it appears I at some point enabled the maximum power saving option in tuned:

```
$ tuned-adm --debug active
Current active profile: powersave
```

I would imagine setting this to something less aggressive would also do the trick, but for now I turned it off completely:

```
$ tuned-adm off
```

More info from https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-tuned:

> As a practical example, consider a typical office workstation. Most of
> the time, the Ethernet network interface is very inactive. Only a few
> emails go in and out every once in a while or some web pages might be
> loaded. For those kinds of loads, the network interface does not have
> to run at full speed all the time, as it does by default. Tuned has a
> monitoring and tuning plug-in for network devices that can detect this
> low activity and then **automatically lower the speed of that interface**,
> typically resulting in a lower power usage. If the activity on the
> interface increases for a longer period of time, for example because a
> DVD image is being downloaded or an email with a large attachment is
> opened, tuned detects this and **sets the interface speed to maximum** to
> offer the best performance while the activity level is so high. This
> principle is used for other plug-ins for CPU and hard disks as well.

Learnings:

- I should really remember it when I enable something like this.
- A little more (than no) verbosity would be lovely when daemons tweak hardware like this.
- I should test more before running off to the hardware store.
- It's not always the kernel's fault ;-)